# LibGDX box2d detection of specific instance of an Object

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d, user-data

I am a little bit confused about beginContact method from box2d.

I have a *Runner* class which is spawning a single runner into the game. In the game I have a multiple runners and I want to detect a collision between a specific instance of a runner and the obstacle.
In *beginContact()* I want to start *hit()* method for a runner who has been hit.

```
public void beginContact(Contact contact) {

    final Body a = contact.getFixtureA().getBody();
    final Body b = contact.getFixtureB().getBody();
    if ((BodyUtils.bodyIsRunner(a) && BodyUtils.bodyIsEnemy(b)) ||
            (BodyUtils.bodyIsEnemy(a) && BodyUtils.bodyIsRunner(b))) {
        Runner c;
        if(BodyUtils.bodyIsRunner(a)) c = (Runner) a.getUserData();
        else c = (Runner) b.getUserData();
        c.hit();
```

But on this line:

`if(BodyUtils.bodyIsRunner(a)) c = (Runner) a.getUserData();`

The game crashes with an exception:

`com.pl.runner.box2d.RunnerUserData cannot be cast to com.pl.runner.entities.Runner`

**I don't know how to deal with this right now so if anyone can give an advice or solution I will be really thankfull. I'm propably missing something basic, I'm stuck with this code for a way too long.**

Here is RunnerUserData class:

```
public class RunnerUserData extends UserData {

    private final Vector2 runningPosition = new Vector2(Constants.RUNNER_X, Constants.RUNNER_Y);
    private final Vector2 dodgePosition = new Vector2(Constants.RUNNER_DODGE_X, Constants.RUNNER_DODGE_Y);
    private Vector2 jumpingLinearImpulse;


    public RunnerUserData(float width, float height) {
        super(width,height);
        jumpingLinearImpulse = Constants.RUNNER_JUMPING_LINEAR_IMPULSE;
        userDataType = UserDataType.RUNNER;
    }

    public Vector2 getJumpingLinearImpulse() {
        return jumpingLinearImpulse;
    }

    public void setJumpingLinearImpulse(Vector2 jumpingLinearImpulse) {
        this.jumpingLinearImpulse = jumpingLinearImpulse;
    }

    public float getHitAngularImpulse() {
        return Constants.RUNNER_HIT_ANGULAR_IMPULSE;
    }

    public float getDodgeAngle() {
        // In radians
        return (float) (-90f * (Math.PI / 180f));
    }

    public Vector2 getRunningPosition() {
        return runningPosition;
    }

    public Vector2 getDodgePosition() {
        return dodgePosition;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because my RunnerUserData have a little bit different role in my game I simply can't pass the *Runner* in body.setUserdata(runner).

So I have a little workaround and it's working fine, maybe it will help someone someday:
in beginContact() method:

```
            Body c;
            if(a.getUserData() instanceof RunnerUserData) c = a;
            else c = b; //checks which body is a runner
            for (Runner r : runners){
                if(r.getUserData() == c.getUserData()){
                    runners.remove(r); 
                    break; //do something if you detect proper runner and quit the loop
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is described quite simply by the exception, you are trying to cast a `RunnerUserData` to a `Runner` which you can't do because `Runner` is not an instance of `RunnerUserData`.

A way around this would be to pass the actual `Runner` object as the user-data e.g. `body.setUserdata(this)` (while in the `Runner` class).

You can use the following to determine whether the fixture's user-data is a `Runner` object:

```
if (body.getUserData() instanceof Runner) {}
```

I recommend making the user-data the object for every body you have, it just makes finding it so much easier.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, 
if (body.getUserData() instanceof Runner) {}
works fine right now but I still can't fire body.hit() inside this condition  because it's simply not a runner.
When I try try to do:
body.setUserdata(this) 
in Runner class it says i can't cast Runner as UserData.